# Update not working using alias and nested select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to update number of records in my table but using combination of alias and nested select I was not able to update and I get this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 37
> Incorrect syntax near 'a'

This is my code:

```
update BranchTagging a set
    Date_End = '2021-12-31 00:00:00'
where Branch_ID in (
    select Branch_ID 
    from ##ForTagging2021
    where code = a.Code 
    and Source_Tagging = a.Source_Tagging
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not allow aliases in the `update`.  So, you could just use the full table name:

```
update BranchTagging 
    set Date_End = '2021-12-31'
where Branch_ID in (select ft.Branch_ID
                    from ##ForTagging2021 ft
                    where ft.code = BranchTagging.Code and
                          ft.Source_Tagging = BranchTagging.Source_Tagging
                   );
```

It seems a little odd to me to use `in` with a correlated subquery.  More typically, I would just use `exists`.

Also, you *can* assign aliases if you use a `from` clause, which would be an alternative way to formulate the query.  The above, though, is standard SQL.